# Facebook app and formview

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using a .net Formview in a Facebook application and the Facebook 5.0 SDK.  As of last week, it worked fine moving between the  and the  views instantenously.  Today, the behavior is different.

When I click on the "edit" button in , it does not go to the edit template.  Rather, it goes through a few URLs and then reloads the page again with the  template.

The two URLS it cycles through are /facebookredirect.axd... and then www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?app_id=....

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  It is a FB bug that should be fixed today.  Here is a link about it: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/discussions/249754